# How to change the timestamp format to string and use it for search function

Tags: php, laravel-8, sql-date-functions

I tried this ,

```
$date = date('D, M dS Y g:i a', strtotime('2018-03-01 11:54:33'));
echo $date; // will print Thu, Mar 01st 2018 11:54 am
```

It worked , but I need same in search function ,

```
 $table->where("main.no", "like", "%$searchfield%")
       ->orWhere("date('D, M dS Y g:i a', strtotime('timestamp'))", "like", "%searchfield%")
```

Here , if i search fri in searchfield input box , its showing error as ,

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Thu, Jan 01st 1970 5:30 am' in 'where clause'
```

I think its trying to convert "fri" to date or something like that.

Comment: What is the name of your column where you search date??

Comment: Your orWhere section does not make much sense as you try to compare a literal value with a pattern. Such a comparison does not have any bearing on what rows you select from the database. You need to have a field name as the first parameter of or Where.

Comment: `strtotime` is not a MySQL function, so cannot be used in the WHERE clause like that. [`date`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) exists in MySQL, but you're calling it with the PHP definition, not the MySQL definition, so it's going to be very confused.

Comment: column name is timestamp  @NIKUNJPATEL

Comment: try `$table->where(function($query) use ($searchfield) {
    $query->where("main.no", "like", "%$searchfield%")
          ->orWhere(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(main.timestamp, '%a, %b %D %Y %h:%i %p')"), "like", "%$searchfield%");
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query for searching in `orWhere` condition:

```
$table->where(function($query) use ($searchfield) {
    $query->where("main.no", "like", "%$searchfield%")
          ->orWhere(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(main.timestamp, '%a, %b %D %Y %h:%i %p')"), "like", "%$searchfield%");
});
```